# Uses unchecked or unsafe operations - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am making my own project in Android Studio and I just got a message, shown in the below image, that I don't understand. Can you guys tell me what it is?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code and errors you're getting here?

Comment: Can you add more details on what you want to archive? Why do you need to have the MainActivity as a static filed, you can use getActivity().

Comment: Can you please post your errors and code as text into your question, not as links or images? The error tells you what's wrong: don't use that particular static variable because it will cause a memory leak and break other things.

Answer (score 1):

You should NEVER EVER EVER hold a static reference to any kind of Activity/Fragment/View. Ever.

Read the error message that is in your screenshot.

Remove the `public static MainActivity ma`.
Any code that relies on that field is a major hack and will cause you a lot of problems further down the line. Guaranteed.

Comment: Then, I have to change it with what?

Comment: That's a completely other question. It all depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

public static MainActivity ma;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent inte = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BuatBiodata.class);
            startActivity(inte);
        }
    });


    ma = this;
    dbcenter = new DataHelper(this);
    RefreshList();
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? If so, combine it with your other answer. If this is not an answer to your question, then you should delete it and just keep your other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, the problem is on the getContext()

It said that getContext() may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) onCreateView().getContext();
    dbcenter = new DataHelper(this);
    RefreshList();
```

Comment: Check out [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) on Meta Stack Exchange to see when you should post multiple answers to one question.